# How to share content title, image and body on Instagram?

Tags: blocks, hooks

I want to share content's title, image and body on Instagram of my Drupal website,

But I am not able to find the solution.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show Instagram feeds in your website ([as in revision 2 of your question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/revisions/183293/2) ...), then there are typically 3 modules to pick from (quotes are from their project pages):

- [Instagram Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/instagram_block):

> ... integrates with Instagram and creates a block containing your most recent instagram posts.

- [Instagram Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/instagram_feeds):

> This is a Feature module. It allows you to create Instagram feeds for your site that will download images from Instagram using filtering by hashtags and / or usernames.

- [Drupagram](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupagram):

> In this early implementation the module will interact with the Instagr.am API and be able to fetch media items. Advanced methods like relationships between Instagr.am users and such will be added later on.

**Note**: posting **to** Instagram doesn't seem to be available, since that isn't allowed through their API (by design).

Comment: Does any of those modules also show the likes of the picture/video?

Comment: @nihilistenhymne That seems like a new  question, why not post a new question about that?

Comment: Hey @nihilistenhymne I just your NEW question. It got put on hold because "is there a module to  ..." is not an acceptabe question on this site (a pitty I think, but these are the rules on this site). I suggest you EDIT your question to include an hyperlink to this question, and ask for something like "which of the 3 modules mentioned in the answer to **this question** can I use for what I want to achieve?". That might help to get your question reopened, ok?